# Is it possible to import individual components from fast-components in Blazor .NET 6?

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, .net-6.0, fast-ui

I have recently been looking at [fast-components](https://www.fast.design/docs/components/accordion) with a Blazor PWA in .NET 6, and in the docs I can see that there is potential for invoking individual components (showing angular syntax, I believe - example below). I would like to bring in individual components with Blazor, however, I'm not sure if this is possible, or how it would be done (potentially using IJSRuntime?)
The [Blazor integration guide does not cover importing individual components](https://www.fast.design/docs/integrations/blazor#getting-started-with-the-fast-components), which leads me to thinking it's not possible, but I hope someone knows otherwise.

Does anyone know how to achieve something like this:

```
import {
    provideFASTDesignSystem,
    fastAccordion,
    fastAccordionItem
} from "@microsoft/fast-components";

provideFASTDesignSystem()
    .register(
        fastAccordion(),
        fastAccordionItem()
    );
```

Using this kind of syntax in Blazor with .NET 6, but to import only a specific component, rather than the whole module?

```
[Inject]
IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
IJSObjectReference module;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./scripts/components/fast-components.min.js");

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by importing individual components? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As an example, if I wanted to use a fast-data-grid on a page, I'd like to import the data grid, only, into the page, instead of the entire JS module